# design of button using angular js

Tags: html, css

I want to change color of the button using angular Js while clicking the button
for first click it should change color and for second click it should go to default color and repeat it

```js
<script>
function setColor(btn, color){
    var count=2;
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    if (count == 0){
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
        count=1;        
    }
    else{
        property.style.backgroundColor = "#A9A9A9"
        count=0;
    }

}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<input type="button" id="button" value = "button"  onclick="setColor('button', '#101010')";/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using combination of `ng-class` & `ng-click` directive. As you could toggle `isSelected` based on `button` click & `ng-class` will take care of which class needs to be apply.

**CSS**

```
.no-color{
  background-color: #FFFFFF
}

.custom-color{
  background-color: #A9A9A9
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" ng-class="{ 'no-color': !isSelected, 'custom-color': isSelected }" 
  value = "button"  ng-click="isSelected = !isSelected"/>
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/HDeznaor14KKVBOCQANW?p=preview)

Comment: Have you checked the plunkr!